# Flowplayer doesn't start under IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flowplayer

I have tried 3 options

```
 <!-- Flowplayer depends on jquery -->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Flowplayer-->
    <script src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // global configuration (optional)
        flowplayer.conf = {
            rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
            swf: "flowplayer.swf"
        };

        // force flash with query - only for testing, do not use this switch in production!
        if (/flash/.test(location.search)) flowplayer.conf.engine = "flash";

        flowplayer.conf.ratio = 0.417;

        // bind listeners to all players on the page
        flowplayer(function (api, root) {

            // when a new video is about to be loaded
            api.bind("load", function () {
                //console.info("load", api.engine);

                // when a video is loaded and ready to play
            }).bind("ready", function () {
                //console.info("ready", api.video.duration)

            });

        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            try {
                // #1  
                flowplayer().play("http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4");

                //#2
                //flowplayer().load([{ mp4: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4" }]).resume();

// #3
//var api = flowplayer();
//api.load("http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4", function () {
//    api.resume();
//});
       } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <!-- first player -->
        <div class="flowplayer ">
            <video preload='none'>
                <source type="video/webm" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm" />
                <source type="video/mp4" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4" />
                <source type="video/ogg" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv" />
               <!-- <source type="video/flash" src="mp4:bauhaus/624x260.mp4" />-->
            </video>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try removing `preload='none'` just to see if it works?  For some reason videos with flowplayer did not work for me if I had preloading "disabled."